# Help identifying two lead component with glass cover and serpentine trace under it

Tags: components, ldr

I ordered an IR pair of components from Amazon and received this which I do not think is an IR emitter or receiver. Does anyone have any ideas to what this component is? I could not find anything by searching.

[image: Photo of the component]

Comment: Your link doesn't work for me. Also, the post editor has a way to add images that will be hosted here (via Imgur), rather than an another external site.

Answer (score 4):

That is an LDR.  A Light-Dependent Resistor.  It is used mostly in voltage-divider circuits that can detect the lowering of resistance in the presence of light.

It is not specific to IR without a filter.

You can wire it like this to detect incident light:

[image]

It looks like this wired to an Arduino Uno:

[image]

You can get the code and some discussion [HERE](https://www.tweaking4all.com/hardware/arduino/arduino-light-sensitive-resistor/)

---

LDRs are handy for detecting both light and dark, which means they can be used in circuits that can turn something on when the light goes away, and vice-versa.

Here is an interesting article that discusses how to do this without a microprocessor:

[LDR Circuit Diagram](http://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/ldr-circuit-diagram/)

---

The OP mentions ordering a pair of IR devices but does not say why.  Note that phototransistors paired with LEDs can be used for much faster switching, like for instance data communications.

Comment: You should add that LDRs respond slowly to light making them nearly useless for communications.  Just in case if that is what the OP was interested in.